# How to design a loop whose stop condition is the emptiness of a container

Tags: c++, loops

I'm sorry for the tricky title, here is the example

```
graph main_graph = //initialize graph
graph sub_graph = //pick a subset of edges from the main_graph
while ( ! sub_graph.size() == 0) {
    select_edge();    //here I pick an edge basing on some heuristics
    reduce_graph();   //here I remove some edges from the main_graph
    sub_graph = //pick a subset of edges from the main_graph
}
```

So the point is that I have to write the very same code to define the `sub_graph` before entering the loop (because it could be already empty) and right before entering a new iteration.
This would not be that bad, if it wasn't that I actually have three nested loops with the same problem, and the code to inizialize the `sub_graph` is a bunch of lines of code, so my code would look a lot replicated.

Any suggestion on how to better design this loop(s)? I have no restrictions (can use `for`, `do-while`...)

Even if this is pseudo-code, since is more a 'design' question, I'm coding in C++!

Comment: Sorry, I already added the language, I'm using boost, but all the methods "called" here are coded by me

Comment: I saw that you added the language after I commented. Sorry about that.

Comment: The question title seems irrelevant to the body; you obviously already know how to stop the loop when the container is empty. You say nested loops pose some sort of problem, but you don't show how. Have you really asked what you intended to?

Comment: my question is related to the code design, I know the title is misleading, but it contains the keyword 'design'

Comment: Apart from functioning-out the relevant code, did you consider `!sub_graph.empty()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid repeating lots of code, put the code in a function:

```
graph calc_subgraph(...) {...}
```

Then use it to initialize and recalculate your values:

```
for (graph subgraph = calc_subgraph(...); subgraph.size() != 0; subgraph = calc_subgraph(...))
```

Comment: Good job, beat me to the punch.

Comment: I'd prefer not to declare other functions, because I'm working on a class that is not mine, so it would be better to modify it as little as possible, but if there aren't any other options (I can't figure out one, that's why I'm asking) I'll accept this answer. Still better than replicating code.

Comment: There's no limit to the number of functions a program may have. Use as many as you need. This new function needn't be a member of the class, if you're really not allowed to modify it. It can be a standalone function instead. Just pass in whatever parameters the function needs to accomplish its task, including parameters passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the code to initialize sub_Graph is a lot of lines, then write a function that returns an initialized graph, or a function that initializes sub_graph via a passed reference/pointer. Then just call the function inside the loop. That will thin the amount of code that you have to write and read. Loops that involve using the same code twice show up from time to time.

Writing loops that output comma separated lists is a good example of this, since you want the commas to stay on the inside of the list items. So you can either do the first item before the loop, or remove a comma after the loop.

In these kind of cases, calling the initializing code before the loop, and then again at the end of each loop iteration may be faster then putting a conditional test in the loop to skip parts of it every time.

Comment: +1 especially for `Loops that involve using the same code twice show up from time to time`. Now I feel better